# Android camera2 qr code reader

Tags: android, qr-code, zxing

I have a fragment which is scanning for a qr code using camera2 API and zxing (google's zebra crossing) API, it works fine for all the phones, the problem is with this specific tablet NVIDIA SHIELD. It would just not find the qr in the image, tried a lot:

1. Smaller, bigger screen/image dimension.
2. All different camera settings like iso, contrast, lighter, darker.
3. Using all image formats like JPEG, YUV_422_888 ...
4. Using planes nr 0,1,2...

Sorry for such a big snippet of code, ask questions, will respond asap.

Here is my code:

```
public class FragmentDecoder extends Fragment
        implements FragmentCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback {

    private static boolean accessGranted = true;
    private static boolean showingText = false;
    private ImageView camera_guide_image;
    private TextView decoderText;
    private ImageButton flashButton;
    private static final int MAX_PREVIEW_WIDTH = 1920;
    private static final int MAX_PREVIEW_HEIGHT = 1080;
    private int mSensorOrientation;
    private boolean mFlashSupported;
    private static final String TAG = FragmentDecoder.class.getName();

    private final CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback mCaptureCallback =
            new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
                private void process(CaptureResult result) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onCaptureProgressed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session, @NonNull CaptureRequest request,
                                                @NonNull CaptureResult partialResult) {
                    process(partialResult);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCaptureCompleted(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session, @NonNull CaptureRequest request,
                                               @NonNull TotalCaptureResult result) {
                    process(result);
                }

            };

    private final TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener mSurfaceTextureListener =
            new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {

                @Override
                public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture texture, int width, int height) {
                    openCamera(width, height);
                }

                @Override
                public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture texture, int width, int height) {
                    configureTransform(width, height);
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture texture) {

                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture texture) {

                }

            };
    private QRCodeReader mQrReader;
    private String mCameraId;
    private AutoFitTextureView mTextureView;
    private final ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener mOnImageAvailableListener =
            new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {

                @Override
                public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
                    Image img = null;
                    Result rawResult = null;
                    try {
                        img = reader.acquireLatestImage();
                        if (img == null) throw new NullPointerException("cannot be null");
                        ByteBuffer buffer = img.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
                        byte[] data = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
                        buffer.get(data);

                        int width = img.getWidth();
                        int height = img.getHeight();

                        PlanarYUVLuminanceSource source = new PlanarYUVLuminanceSource(data, width, height, 0, 0, width, height, false);
                        BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));

                        rawResult = mQrReader.decode(bitmap);

                        if (rawResult == null) {
                            throw new NullPointerException("no QR code");
                        }
                        String decoded = rawResult.getText();

                        if (accessGranted) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "entered the accessGranted area!");
                            accessGranted = false;
                            boolean isPrivKey = BRWalletManager.getInstance(getActivity()).confirmSweep(getActivity(), decoded);
                            if (isPrivKey) {
                                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        BRAnimator.hideDecoderFragment();
                                    }
                                });
                                return;
                            }

                            String validationString = validateResult(decoded);

                            if (Objects.equals(validationString, BRConstants.TEXT_EMPTY)) {
                                onQRCodeRead((MainActivity) getActivity(), rawResult.getText());
                            } else {
                                if (!showingText) {
                                    showingText = true;
                                    setCameraGuide(BRConstants.CAMERA_GUIDE_RED);
                                    setGuideText(validationString);
                                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {
                                            showingText = false;
                                        }
                                    }, 1000);
                                }
                                accessGranted = true;
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (ReaderException | NullPointerException | IllegalStateException ignored) {
                        if (!showingText)
                            setCameraGuide(BRConstants.CAMERA_GUIDE);
//                        Log.e(TAG, "Reader shows an exception! ", ignored);
                        /* Ignored */
                    } finally {
                        mQrReader.reset();
                        if (img != null)
                            img.close();

                    }
                    if (rawResult == null) {
                        if (!showingText)
                            setCameraGuide(BRConstants.CAMERA_GUIDE);
                    }
                }

            };
    private CameraCaptureSession mCaptureSession;
    private CameraDevice mCameraDevice;
    private final CameraDevice.StateCallback mStateCallback = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onOpened(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice) {
            // This method is called when the camera is opened.  We start camera preview here.
            mCameraOpenCloseLock.release();
            mCameraDevice = cameraDevice;
            createCameraPreviewSession();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDisconnected(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice) {
            mCameraOpenCloseLock.release();
            cameraDevice.close();
            mCameraDevice = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice, int error) {
            mCameraOpenCloseLock.release();
            cameraDevice.close();
            mCameraDevice = null;
            getActivity().onBackPressed();
        }

    };

    private Size mPreviewSize;
    private HandlerThread mBackgroundThread;
    private Handler mBackgroundHandler;
    private ImageReader mImageReader;
    private CaptureRequest.Builder mPreviewRequestBuilder;
    private CaptureRequest mPreviewRequest;
    private final Semaphore mCameraOpenCloseLock = new Semaphore(1);
    private int flashButtonCount;


    private static Size chooseOptimalSize(Size[] choices, int textureViewWidth,
                                          int textureViewHeight, int maxWidth, int maxHeight, Size aspectRatio) {


        List<Size> bigEnough = new ArrayList<>();

        List<Size> notBigEnough = new ArrayList<>();
        int w = aspectRatio.getWidth();
        int h = aspectRatio.getHeight();
        for (Size option : choices) {
            if (option.getWidth() <= maxWidth && option.getHeight() <= maxHeight &&
                    option.getHeight() == option.getWidth() * h / w) {
                if (option.getWidth() >= textureViewWidth &&
                        option.getHeight() >= textureViewHeight) {
                    bigEnough.add(option);
                } else {
                    notBigEnough.add(option);
                }
            }
        }

        // Pick the smallest of those big enough. If there is no one big enough, pick the

        if (bigEnough.size() > 0) {
            return Collections.min(bigEnough, new CompareSizesByArea());
        } else if (notBigEnough.size() > 0) {
            return Collections.max(notBigEnough, new CompareSizesByArea());
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't find any suitable preview size");
            return choices[0];
        }
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_decoder, container, false);
        mQrReader = new QRCodeReader();

        mTextureView = new AutoFitTextureView(getActivity());
        RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_decoder_layout);
        camera_guide_image = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.decoder_camera_guide_image);
        decoderText = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.decoder_text);
        flashButton = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button_flash);
        flashButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                try {
                    if (mPreviewRequestBuilder == null || mCaptureSession == null)
                        return;

                    if (++flashButtonCount % 2 != 0) {
                        mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE, CameraMetadata.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                        mCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(mPreviewRequestBuilder.build(), null, null);
                        flashButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.flash_on);
                        SpringAnimator.showAnimation(flashButton);
                    } else {
                        mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE, CameraMetadata.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                        mCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(mPreviewRequestBuilder.build(), null, null);
                        flashButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.flash_off);
                        SpringAnimator.showAnimation(flashButton);
                    }
                } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        layout.addView(mTextureView, 0);
        startBackgroundThread();
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        accessGranted = true;
        showingText = false;
        new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (camera_guide_image != null)

                    SpringAnimator.showExpandCameraGuide(camera_guide_image);
            }
        });
        ((BreadWalletApp) getActivity().getApplication()).hideKeyboard(getActivity());

        // When the screen is turned off and turned back on, the SurfaceTexture is already
        // available, and "onSurfaceTextureAvailable" will not be called. In that case, we can open
        // a camera and start preview from here (otherwise, we wait until the surface is ready in
        // the SurfaceTextureListener).

        if (mTextureView.isAvailable()) {
            openCamera(mTextureView.getWidth(), mTextureView.getHeight());
        } else {
            mTextureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(mSurfaceTextureListener);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        closeCamera();
        stopBackgroundThread();
        super.onPause();
    }

    private void setUpCameraOutputs(int width, int height) {
        Activity activity = getActivity();
        CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        try {
            for (String cameraId : manager.getCameraIdList()) {
                CameraCharacteristics characteristics
                        = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);

                // We don't use a front facing camera in this sample.
                Integer facing = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING);
                if (facing != null && facing == CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT) {
                    continue;
                }

                StreamConfigurationMap map = characteristics.get(
                        CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
                if (map == null) {
                    continue;
                }

                // For still image captures, we use the largest available size.
                Size largest = Collections.max(
                        Arrays.asList(map.getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.YUV_420_888)),
                        new CompareSizesByArea());
                mImageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(largest.getWidth()/2, largest.getHeight()/2,
                        ImageFormat.YUV_420_888, /*maxImages*/2);
                mImageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(
                        mOnImageAvailableListener, mBackgroundHandler);

                // Find out if we need to swap dimension to get the preview size relative to sensor
                // coordinate.
                int displayRotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
                //noinspection ConstantConditions
                mSensorOrientation = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_ORIENTATION);
                boolean swappedDimensions = false;
                switch (displayRotation) {
                    case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                    case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                        if (mSensorOrientation == 90 || mSensorOrientation == 270) {
                            swappedDimensions = true;
                        }
                        break;
                    case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                    case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                        if (mSensorOrientation == 0 || mSensorOrientation == 180) {
                            swappedDimensions = true;
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        Log.e(TAG, "Display rotation is invalid: " + displayRotation);
                }

                Point displaySize = new Point();
                activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(displaySize);
                int rotatedPreviewWidth = width;
                int rotatedPreviewHeight = height;
                int maxPreviewWidth = displaySize.x;
                int maxPreviewHeight = displaySize.y;

                if (swappedDimensions) {
                    rotatedPreviewWidth = height;
                    rotatedPreviewHeight = width;
                    maxPreviewWidth = displaySize.y;
                    maxPreviewHeight = displaySize.x;
                }

                if (maxPreviewWidth > MAX_PREVIEW_WIDTH) {
                    maxPreviewWidth = MAX_PREVIEW_WIDTH;
                }

                if (maxPreviewHeight > MAX_PREVIEW_HEIGHT) {
                    maxPreviewHeight = MAX_PREVIEW_HEIGHT;
                }

                // Danger, W.R.! Attempting to use too large a preview size could  exceed the camera
                // bus' bandwidth limitation, resulting in gorgeous previews but the storage of
                // garbage capture data.
                mPreviewSize = chooseOptimalSize(map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class),
                        rotatedPreviewWidth, rotatedPreviewHeight, maxPreviewWidth,
                        maxPreviewHeight, largest);

                // We fit the aspect ratio of TextureView to the size of preview we picked.
                int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
                if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
                    mTextureView.setAspectRatio(
                            mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight());
                } else {
                    mTextureView.setAspectRatio(
                            mPreviewSize.getHeight(), mPreviewSize.getWidth());
                }

                // Check if the flash is supported.
                Boolean available = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.FLASH_INFO_AVAILABLE);
                mFlashSupported = available == null ? false : available;

                mCameraId = cameraId;
                return;
            }
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void openCamera(int width, int height) {
        setUpCameraOutputs(width, height);
        configureTransform(width, height);
        CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        try {
            if (!mCameraOpenCloseLock.tryAcquire(2500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Time out waiting to lock camera opening.");
            }
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return;
            }
            if (mCameraId != null)
                manager.openCamera(mCameraId, mStateCallback, mBackgroundHandler);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Interrupted while trying to lock camera opening.", e);
        }
    }


    private void closeCamera() {
        try {
            mCameraOpenCloseLock.acquire();
            if (mCaptureSession != null) {
                mCaptureSession.close();
                mCaptureSession = null;
            }
            if (mCameraDevice != null) {
                mCameraDevice.close();
                mCameraDevice = null;
            }
            if (mImageReader != null) {
                mImageReader.close();
                mImageReader = null;
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Interrupted while trying to lock camera closing.", e);
        } finally {
            mCameraOpenCloseLock.release();
        }
    }

    private void startBackgroundThread() {
        mBackgroundThread = new HandlerThread("CameraBackground");
        mBackgroundThread.start();
        mBackgroundHandler = new Handler(mBackgroundThread.getLooper());
    }

    private void stopBackgroundThread() {
        try {
            mBackgroundThread.quitSafely();
            mBackgroundThread.join();
            mBackgroundThread = null;
            mBackgroundHandler = null;
        } catch (InterruptedException | NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            mBackgroundThread = null;
            mBackgroundHandler = null;
        }
    }

    private void createCameraPreviewSession() {
        try {
            SurfaceTexture texture = mTextureView.getSurfaceTexture();
            assert texture != null;

            // We configure the size of default buffer to be the size of camera preview we want.
            texture.setDefaultBufferSize(mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight());

            Surface surface = new Surface(texture);
            Surface mImageSurface = mImageReader.getSurface();
            mPreviewRequestBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
            mPreviewRequestBuilder.addTarget(mImageSurface);
            mPreviewRequestBuilder.addTarget(surface);

            // Here, we create a CameraCaptureSession for camera preview.
            mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(mImageSurface, surface),
                    new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                            // The camera is already closed
//                            Log.e(TAG, "onConfigured");
                            if (mCameraDevice == null) return;

                            // When the session is ready, we start displaying the preview.
                            mCaptureSession = cameraCaptureSession;
                            try {
                                // Auto focus should be continuous for camera preview.
                                mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CONTROL_AF_MODE, CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);



                                mPreviewRequest = mPreviewRequestBuilder.build();
                                mCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(mPreviewRequest, mCaptureCallback,
                                        mBackgroundHandler);
                            } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.failed),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }, null
            );
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void configureTransform(int viewWidth, int viewHeight) {

        if (mTextureView == null || mPreviewSize == null) return;

        int rotation = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        RectF viewRect = new RectF(0, 0, viewWidth, viewHeight);
        RectF bufferRect = new RectF(0, 0, mPreviewSize.getHeight(), mPreviewSize.getWidth());
        float centerX = viewRect.centerX();
        float centerY = viewRect.centerY();
        if (Surface.ROTATION_90 == rotation || Surface.ROTATION_270 == rotation) {
            bufferRect.offset(centerX - bufferRect.centerX(), centerY - bufferRect.centerY());
            matrix.setRectToRect(viewRect, bufferRect, Matrix.ScaleToFit.FILL);
            float scale = Math.max(
                    (float) viewHeight / mPreviewSize.getHeight(),
                    (float) viewWidth / mPreviewSize.getWidth());
            matrix.postScale(scale, scale, centerX, centerY);
            matrix.postRotate(90 * (rotation - 2), centerX, centerY);
        }
        mTextureView.setTransform(matrix);
    }

    private static synchronized void onQRCodeRead(final MainActivity app, final String text) {
        app.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (text != null) {
                    BRAnimator.hideDecoderFragment();
                    Log.e(TAG, "BEFORE processRequest");
                    RequestHandler.processRequest(app, text);

                }
            }
        });

    }


    private static class CompareSizesByArea implements Comparator<Size> {

        @Override
        public int compare(Size lhs, Size rhs) {
            // We cast here to ensure the multiplications won't overflow
            return Long.signum((long) lhs.getWidth() * lhs.getHeight() -
                    (long) rhs.getWidth() * rhs.getHeight());
        }

    }

    private int getStatusBarHeight() {
        Rect rectangle = new Rect();
        Window window = getActivity().getWindow();
        window.getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rectangle);
        int statusBarHeight = rectangle.top;
        int contentViewTop =
                window.findViewById(Window.ID_ANDROID_CONTENT).getTop();
        int titleBarHeight = contentViewTop - statusBarHeight;


        return statusBarHeight + titleBarHeight;
    }

    private String validateResult(String str) {
        RequestObject obj = null;
        try {
            obj = RequestHandler.getRequestFromString(str);
        } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.fragmentdecoder_not_a_bitcoin_qr_code);
        }
        if (obj.r != null) {
            return BRConstants.TEXT_EMPTY;
        }
        if (obj.address != null) {
            if (BRWalletManager.validateAddress(obj.address)) {
                return BRConstants.TEXT_EMPTY;
            } else {
                return getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.fragmentdecoder_not_valid_bitcoin_address);
            }
        }
        return getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.fragmentdecoder_not_a_bitcoin_qr_code);
    }

    private void setCameraGuide(final String str) {
        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (str.equalsIgnoreCase(BRConstants.CAMERA_GUIDE)) {
                    camera_guide_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.cameraguide);
                    setGuideText(BRConstants.TEXT_EMPTY);
                } else if (str.equalsIgnoreCase(BRConstants.CAMERA_GUIDE_RED)) {
                    camera_guide_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.cameraguide_red);

                } else {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("CAMERA_GUIDE and CAMERA_GUIDE_RED only");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void setGuideText(final String str) {
        Activity activity = getActivity();
        if (activity != null)
            activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    decoderText.setText(str);
                }
            });

    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried taking a photograph with the tablet in question, and then running it through a separate QR code reader on some other machine? I'd like to know whether the problem is the code or the camera. Also take a look at https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/892855/android-development/no-camera-from-shield-tablet-open-source-binary-driver-release/ which suggests that the Shield camera support on Android is missing some drivers.

Comment: good point, I will try, so you think this can be a NVIDIA bug or something related to the hardware? since I have 7 different phones and all scan pretty well, I don't have any other tablets though and I wonder if the problem is tablet specific.

Comment: Yeah, that comment on the NVIDIA forum sounds like someone has the precise same application that you do, with similar frustrating results.

Comment: thanks man, I guess you're right.